# Deploying inherited classes on my contract

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm recreating a remix like environment that can compile and deploy solidity contracts as a way to better understand the deployment process.

I'm currently testing with a contract that generates a simple BEP20 token: https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/issue-BEP20.html

My question has to do with deploying inherited classes. In the case of this BEP20 contract, when I compile it using solc.js I get an abi and bytecode output for 5 different instances:
BEP20Token, Context, IBEP20, Ownable, & SafeMath.

In this case, do I need to deploy all 5 pieces as separate contracts? Can I combine the abi and bycodes for each? What is the standard process for doing this?

For context, I attempting to deploy the contract using ethers.js.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Usually contracts inherit each other and form the required functionality together.

If you have three contracts `A`, `B` and `C`, where `A is B` and `B is C`, then you can deploy any one of these contracts (assuming they are not abstract/interface contracts). If you deploy `C`, the deployed contract only has the functionality from contract `C`. If you deploy `A`, then it has the functionality from all three contracts.

In reality, there is no inheritance at the bytecode level. All contracts are flattened: `A` has all of the functionality from `A`, `B` and `C` written inside the same contract. The same is probably true for ABIs: it includes the ABI for the deployed contract (including possible inheritance).

So, in the end, you should typically just deploy the lower-most contract, since that has all of the functionality from other contracts.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was assuming, but I was a little concerned when I tried to add the source code to bscscan. It showed that the compiled contract on has contract A, while what I was trying to upload includes contracts A, B, C, etc.